# Is it possible to access the read buffer on a socket that has thrown IOException?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have an application that sends a lot of data with the TcpClient class using the asynchronous BeginWrite method. To save cycles on reading and send my payload as fast as possible I don't read anything from the ReceiveBuffer until all the sending is done. I've set the ReceiveBuffer to a sufficiently large size so that it can capture all the responses.

The problem is that sometimes the connection is reset/closed during sending (System.IO.IOException: Unable to **write** data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine). I recover from this by creating a new TcpClient, re-establishing the connection and continuing to send. However the socket that I was using to send before is now closed and I am unable to read the buffer that it has received so far. Is there any way to recover the data in the ReceiveBuffer of that socket?

Some more information:
I am creating an SslStream from the underlying NetworkStream provided by TcpClient and sending data over that. Sometimes the response from the server contains Connection: close in the HTTP header. And I guess the SslStream closes itself and eventually the Socket. Since I don't normally read responses during my send cycle, I am not aware of receiving Connection: close. After this occurs the next attempt to write to the SslStream seems to fail silently, as in there is no exception, but no response is received back from the server either. The next attempt to write to SslStream after that results in the IOException.

I have tried checking the state of the socket, and stream in various ways such as Socket.Connected, Socket.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectWrite), SslStream.CanWrite. All of them come back True all the time including right before the IOException is thrown on a write attempt.

Comment: Have you tried reading in the `IOException` handler, before closing the socket?  Reads should eventually fail with the same "connection has been aborted or reset" cause, but not until after you're emptied the buffer.

Comment: Attempting to read from the socket results in "System.IO.IOException: Unable to **read** data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."